# How to find MySQL users causing high load?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL server with multiple websites running on it. These sites are mostly the same software, but since recently MySQL is under very high CPU load.

I'm pretty sure there is 1 MySQL user that is causing the higher load, but how can I identify the resources used per user?

I know I can limit the number of connections and number of queries per user, but before enforcing limits, I want to know what the current numbers are.

How can this be measured (in MySQL 5.7)?

Answer (score 2):

The performance schema provides statistics aggregated by account (user + host), by user, and by host.

See for example table:

```
performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name
```

Reference manual
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/statement-summary-tables.html

This table will show statement statistics (aka, queries) broken down per account ... anyone causing heavy traffic (high number of queries) or expensive computation (a few very expensive and long latencies queries) should be very visible in these statistics.

[Edit] Example of query:

```
select `USER`, `HOST`, SUM(COUNT_STAR) AS TOTAL
  from events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name
  group by `USER`, `HOST`
  order by TOTAL DESC;
```

will show how many queries each account do, ordered by count descending.

Comment: Thanks! But, which columns should I be looking at here? Or should I add some columns to get the full load causes by this user?

Comment: @Wouter See the edit, I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be even better to give the naughty users a clue of what to fix?  Turn on the slowlog, gather its results, and present to the 'worse' users their 'worst' queries.

As for limiting what a user can do, it is quite difficult in a shared instance.  About the only thing available is `max_user_connections`.  But that does nothing to the runaway queries that chew up a CPU core or lots of I/O.

Somewhat related is the setting for `sql_safe_updates`.  It is aimed at runaway updates and deletes, but has the side effect of stopping such queries.

If each user had his own instance of MySQL, "cgroups" is excellent at keeping one user from hogging the system -- except when no one else is busy.  Win-win.  There are other hassles with running multiple instances, so I am not necessarily recommending such.